# How to handle multiple endpoints via grpc-gateway?

Tags: go, go-micro, grpc-gateway

**I'm sure all the services are working properly.**

I have the code below:

This snippet is used for registering two endpoints.

```golang
func RegisterEndpoints(ctx context.Context, c *utils.AppConfig, r resolver.Builder) (http.Handler, error) {
    var err error
    mux := runtime.NewServeMux()
    dialOpts := []grpc.DialOption{grpc.WithBalancerName("round_robin"), grpc.WithInsecure()}

    err = protos.RegisterUserCenterHandlerFromEndpoint(ctx, mux, r.Scheme()+"://author/user-center", dialOpts)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    err = protos.RegisterSsoHandlerFromEndpoint(ctx, mux, r.Scheme()+"://author/sso", dialOpts)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    return mux, nil
}
```

And in my `main.go`，I build a resolver to resolve name to address, then register the two endpoints and listen on port 8080.

```golang
func run() error {
    c := utils.GetAppConfig()

    ctx := context.Background()
    ctx, cancel := context.WithCancel(ctx)
    defer cancel()

    r := localresolver.NewResolver(fmt.Sprintf("%s:%d", c.Registry.Host, c.Registry.Port))
    resolver.Register(r)

    mux := http.NewServeMux()

    // Register endpoints here
    gw, err := routes.RegisterEndpoints(ctx, c, r)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    mux.Handle("/", gw)
    fmt.Println("Listening localhost:8080...")
    return http.ListenAndServe(fmt.Sprintf("%s:%d", c.Gateway.Host, c.Gateway.Port), mux)
}

func main() {
    defer glog.Flush()

    if err := run(); err != nil {
        glog.Fatal(err)
    }
}
```

But after I ran `go run main.go`, I found that only the last service I registered can be accessed, that is `sso` service (the `err = protos.RegisterSsoHandlerFromEndpoint(ctx, mux, r.Scheme()+"://author/sso", dialOpts)` line).

Can anyone show me an example of the correct way to register multiple endpoints via `grpc-gateway`? (make all the services registered with `grpc-gateway` can successfully be visited)

---

[2020-01-31] Need more help, now my code is like below:

[image: the latest code]

Other code are same as before.

Additional, this is the result which name resolver shows:

[image: name resolver resolves the addresses]

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to pass the `ServeMux` (gw) to mux var as handler, you can just ListenAndServe to the returned `gw` variable.

```golang
    // Register endpoints here
    gw, err := routes.RegisterEndpoints(ctx, c, r)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    fmt.Println("Listening localhost:8080...")
    return http.ListenAndServe(fmt.Sprintf("%s:%d", c.Gateway.Host, c.Gateway.Port), gw)
```

and in `RegisterEndpoints` function, the endpoint parameter should be your `host:port`, the api endpoint should be provided in the google api annotation in the proto file.

```golang
    err = protos.RegisterUserCenterHandlerFromEndpoint(ctx, mux, fmt.Sprintf("%s:%d", c.Gateway.Host, c.Gateway.Port), dialOpts)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    err = protos.RegisterSsoHandlerFromEndpoint(ctx, mux, fmt.Sprintf("%s:%d", c.Gateway.Host, c.Gateway.Port), dialOpts)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
```

Comment: Appreciate your answer, but follow your advice, it still can't work. In my case, I use `etcd` as the registry, so the two service `user-center` and `sso` have different `host:port` pairs, so I use `r` as the resolver to tell gRPC to resolve the address. After I launched the `grpc-gateway` service, both addresses of them are discovered, but still only the last registered one can be accessed. Hope more help.

Comment: I've updated this question to show more detail, looking forward to your reply.

Answer (score 0):

I appended `grpc.WithBlock()` to `grpc.DialOption`, then all services can be accessed via `grpc-gateway` now.

Like below:

```golang
dialOpts := []grpc.DialOption{grpc.WithBalancerName("round_robin"), grpc.WithInsecure(), grpc.WithBlock()}
```